# fadeToggle() does not respect hierarchy in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to use fadeToggle () in the comments section of my blog to open the reply form to existing comments. Initially I'm using `display: none` in CSS to hide both the comments list and the form. The fadeIn/Out actions should be performed by clicking on the 'Reply' link. However, when I click on reply, I go straight to the top of the page and the fade effect doesn't take effect. I reviewed the hierarchy in the html to make sure that the fadeToggle function would be redirected to the correct class, but even so, something is not correct.

**html**

```
{% for comment in comments %}
<blockquote class="blockquote">
  <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
  <footer class="blockquote-footer">Por: {{ comment.user }} | {{ comment.timestamp|timesince }} ago |
    {% if comment.children.count > 0 %}{{ comment.children.count }} comment{% if comment.children.count > 1 %}s
    {% endif %} | {% endif %}<a class="comment-reply-btn" href="#">Reply</a>
  </footer>
  <div class="comment-reply">
    {% for child_comment in comment.children %}
    <blockquote class="blockquote">
      <p class="mb-0">{{ child_comment.content }}</p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer">Por: {{ child_comment.user }} |
        {{ child_comment.timestamp|timesince }}
        ago
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <form action="" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ comment_form|crispy }}
      <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{ comment.id }}">
      <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" value="Reply">
    </form>
    {% else %}
    <p>You must login to reply</p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</blockquote>
{% endfor %}
```

**css**

```
.comment-reply {
  display: none;
}
```

**js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".comment-reply-btn").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().next(".comment-reply").fadeToggle();
      })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: can you add html instead of code? it's enough a section in order to debug your issue

Comment: Something is going wrong with the JS. Check the Console of your browser's Developer Tools for errors.

Comment: *when I click on reply, I go straight to the top of the page* - sounds like your "reply" is submitting the form.  Which "Reply" button are you clicking? There's two `<input class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" value="Reply">`.   A [mcve] will help us help you.

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm referring to the first reply in the <a> tag.

Comment: If you're loading the code with the `.comment-reply-btn` *after* the page has loaded (eg via an ajax request) then you'll need event delegation.  Are you loading the code with the `.comment-reply-btn` *after* the page has loaded?